# C# динамические поля в классе ссылкой на другой объект класса

Tags: c#, классы, структуры-данных, типы-данных, динамические-структуры

Нужно реализовать класс "Node" у него есть динамические поля List:

список string

список int

список какие объекты класса "Node" на него ссылаются

список на какие объекты класса "Node" он ссылается.

Желательный пример обращения с будущем реализованным классом

```
 Node.ListConstInt[i] = 111; //Node.ListConstInt[1] хранит 111;
 Node.ListConstInt.add(666); //Node.ListConstInt[2] хранит 666;
 Node.ListConstInt.count;//число количество элементов сейчас там 2
 Node.InListRef[i]//вернет объект класса "Node"
```

Пример моей заготовки

```
class ClassNode
    {
        private List<int> _InConst;
        private List<string> _InString;
        private int _OutConst;
        private string _OutString;
        private List<ClassNode> _InReference;
        private List<ClassNode> _OutReference;
        public int this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return _InConst[index];
            }
            set
            {
                _InConst[index] =value;
            }
        }
        public List<string> InString { get; set; }
        public int OutConst { get; set; }
        public string OutString { get; set; }
        //как сделать ссылки на классы             
        public List<ClassNode> InReference { get; set; }
        public List<ClassNode> OutReference { get; set; }
        public string Operator { get; set; }
        public string Index { get; set; }
        public int Tier { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Перечитал 5 раз, не могу понять, что вы написали. Перечитайте и отредактируйте вопрос, расставьте запятые, добавьте деталей, быть может понятнее странет.

Comment: Ну ок, и в чём у вас сложность?

Comment: С созданием списков и реализации ссылок. Не могу доставить элемент в поле класса. Как организовать ссылки

Comment: Ну вы хотя бы какую-то заготовку нарисуйте для методов вашего класса. Пока вы как-то даже и не попытались.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ClassNode
    {
        public List<int> ListInConst { get; set; }
        public List<string> ListInString { get; set; } 
        public int OutConst { get; set; }
        public string OutString { get; set; } 
        public List<ClassNode> ListInReference { get; set; }
        public List<ClassNode> ListOutReference { get; set; }
        //public List<какой нибуть класс который будет ссылкой на другой обект> opAdds { get; set; }

        public string Operator { get; set; }
        public string Index { get; set; }
        public int Tier { get; set; }
    }

    class OptimizeClassNode
    {

        public void foo()
        {
            List<ClassNode> ListNode = new List<ClassNode>();
            ClassNode Node = new ClassNode();
            Node.ListInReference = new List<ClassNode>();
            Node.ListInReference.Add(Node);
            Node.OutConst = 2;
            Node.ListInConst = new List<int>();
            Node.ListInConst.Add(3);
            ListNode.Add(Node);

        }


    }




    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OptimizeClassNode node = new OptimizeClassNode();
            node.foo();

        }
    }
```